# Getting back bytes object instead of uploaded file

Tags: python, file-upload, python-3.x, bytesio

Python 3.2, Apache, no framework

I have a form to upload a file:

```
<form action="Files/Admin/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload_file" style="width:100%">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload">
</form>
```

There's also a few select boxes, but I didn't want to confuse the issue.  The end goal is to encrypt the given file, and store it somewhere, which will then be decrypted later and given back.  I managed to get the encrypt/decrypt working, but instead of a pdf file, I ended up with a byte string (opened in a browser it said:

```
b'%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ <snip...>
```

So I stripped out the encryption and decryption and saving, and I'm now just trying to make it give me back the exact file I just uploaded:

```
import cgi
tmp = cgi.FieldStorage()
dat = tmp['upload_file']
import mimetypes
gtype,encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(dat.filename)
print ('Content-type:', gtype+'\n')
print (dat.file.read())
```

That gives me:

[image: Adobe Error]

I've tried it with two different pdfs, now, and both give the same message.

A text file gives back a byte string of the original text:

```
b'STUFF - \xa7112.7\r\n1\r\nSTUFF\r\n8\r\nSTUFF <snip...>
```

Changing the code to include disposition:

```
import cgi
tmp = cgi.FieldStorage()
dat = tmp['upload_file']
import mimetypes
gtype,encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(dat.filename)
print ('Content-type:', gtype)
print ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'+dat.filename+'"\n')
print (dat.file.read())
```

and using the text file gives me the usual download or save, but the text file is just the same byte string, not the actual file.

I've spent the last day trying to find the exact right combination of words that will make Google give me the answer, but of the (very few, surprisingly) results that are at all applicable, they all act as if this is an elementary operation and should just work. I've found stuff talking about reading from binary files and to open them correctly, except the uploaded file is a temp file, not a saved file, it's in memory and open is not a valid method for it.  I've also seen stuff on setting up file servers in python, but they're talking about setting up actual servers, not just spitting out a a single file.  Do I need to set up a full blown server to get back a file?

I'm sure I'm making some incredibly stupid rookie mistake, here, but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: The obvious way to debug this is to log `hashlib.sha1(dat.file.read())` and compare that against the checksum. If the checksums match, your delivery mechanism is at fault, otherwise, it may also be a problem with the form.

Comment: From Idle, hashlib.sha1(dat.read()).hexdigest() gives me da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709.  From the upload it's 91a5bc150e962b534fd1550cfc31ff88e527c129  So they're not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` always includes an additional newline, which breaks the binary PDF file. Pass the `end=` parameter or write to `sys.stdout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import cgi
tmp = cgi.FieldStorage()
dat = tmp['upload_file']
import mimetypes
gtype,encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(dat.filename)

sys.stdout.buffer.write (b'Content-type:' + gtype.encode('ascii') + b'\r\n\r\n')
sys.stdout.buffer.write (dat.file.read())
```

Comment: @user1178991 Can you put up a public test server that demonstrates the problem? Also, what is the sha1sum of 1. the file you're uploading 2. `data.file.read()` 3. The file you've downloaded?

Comment: Unless someone knows of a public/free server with python installed, my only other option would be the company website, which would be bad.  And I replied to your other comment, but to repeat, the hex of a local version opened in Idle, and the hex of the uploaded version do NOT match.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem with Apache 2.2.22-11 on debian Linux amd64. Are you by any chance on Windows? If so, could you retry the updated answer?

Comment: I am on windows locally, though it'll be Ubuntu when live.  The updated answer gives me: line 23, in Upload
    sys.stdout.write (dat.file.read())
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
If I str it, it's the same byte string.

Comment: @user1178991 Does it fail on both local and live? Oops, the version was indeed erroneous. Can you retry with the updated one? Also, in the absence of a live server, a [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) pcap dump of the file (upload at dropbox, github, bitbucket or so) would be most helpful.

Comment: That's it, that did it.  I can now get back a text file.  Thank you so much!